# Sql Query to C# with entity framework or linq

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have this sql expression and I want to convert it into a code syntax using entity framework or linq

```
select [Key],name from products where [Key] not in (select distinct parent from products where parent is not null)
```

Comment: I don't know how to do that I am a still a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, may be it can help you

```
var p = products.Where(p => p.parent != null).select(p=>p.parent).Distinct();

var pro = products.Where(p => !p.Contains(p.Key))
                   .Select(p => new { ProKey = p.Key, ProName.Name });
```

May be its will work, and still you having problem that let me know...

Comment: Thanks ! It worked but do you have any suggestions for mixing it to one query ?

Comment: Instead of mixing, this query in one query, I suggest you to use it on this way because it will be easy, else there will be lots of complicate...

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
var parents = products.Where(p => p.parent != null).Distinct();

var products = products.Where(p => !parents.Contains(p.Key))
                       .Select(p => new { p.Key, p.Name });
```

Comment: !parents.Contains(p.Key) gives me an error, I am not sure why but p.parent and p.key are of type GUID or uniqueidentifier in the database

Comment: @MohamedNaguib Saying it gives you an error really doesn't help me I'm afraid as I need to know the specific details so I can amend the code.